# Bypass Windows Startup Repair

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have a Windows 7 computer which always starts up into "Startup Repair". Startup Repair always fails saying that it cannot repair the computer and then proceeds to shutdown the computer. I have tried Safe Mode and Safe Mode Command Prompt Only. Neither of them let me bypass the startup repair.

Is there any way to bypass the startup repair to at least get to a command prompt? I've googled for this problem and everyone recommends using the following command (but I can't get to a command prompt to execute it):

```
bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No
```

Comment: You can use **Shift+F10** to enter in command prompt.

Comment: Have you the Windows-7 installation disk?

Comment: @avirk - no, I don't have access to the Windows 7 disk

Comment: @avirk - Do you mean Shift+F10 during the Startup Repair? I was pressing F8 and choosing Command Prompt from the menu there while booting up.

Comment: Yes I mean during `startup repair`. Pressing F8 will let you choose the `safe mode`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open the command prompt during the `startup repair`  and can run that command.

I assume that you have the Windows-7 bootable disk. So then its very easy to get back you system working again. Before this enter to bios setup and check that your default boot device is CD/DVD drive, if it is not then set it to your default boot device. Follow the steps given below:

**1:** Insert the Windows 7 installation disc and restart the PC and press any key when prompted.

**2:** Select your language preferences and click on Next. Click on Repair your computer.

[image]

**3:** Select which operating system you want to restore and the click on Next.

**NOTE:** *If Windows 7 is not listed here, or it is blank, then it is ok. Click on Next anyway.*

**4:** Select the system recovery option you want to do.

[image]

Here you have to select the ***Command Prompt*** and then run that command. You can also try the `Bootrec /fixmbr` and `Bootrec /fixboot` to fix the problem.

If that doesn't help then you can try few more things as I have found it on [seveforum](http://www.sevenforums.com/backup-restore/94457-windows-unable-start-startup-repair-system-restore-wont-work.html). Just follow these steps after entering in **Command Prompt**

> **1:** On Command Line acessed the folder with the files that should substitute `C:\Windows\System32\Config`. To do that,  type **cd windows**, then **cd system32**, then **cd config**
>
> **2:** Type 'dir' to see the files. There were 5 files with the termination **.gbck**, and 5 files without any termination. They are the following files: **DEFAULT, SAM, SECURITY, SOFTWARE and SYSTEM**.
>
> **3:** Rename all the files without termination to **.bak** one by one. just like that: **ren COMPONENTS COMPONENTS.bak** (you should do it for the others 4 files)
>
> **4:** Rename all the **.gbck** to without termination one by one. just like that: **ren COMPONENTS.gbck COMPONENTS** (you should do it for the others 4 files)
>
> **5:** Type **dir**, to see if the files names were exactly you are expecting to.
>
> **6** Restart the PC.

Comment: I think this repair only applies to problems resulting from using Glary Utilities?, other W7 startup repair loop repair is here.....http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/139576-startup-repair-infinite-loop-recovery.html

Comment: @Moab really a good one from them. But I don't think that this time user had problem of infinity as he marked it solve now.

Comment: glad to meed someone from India here at SuperUser.